# how to write a regex for this string: (RA pp 24-25; 2 AA pp. 184-185, 194-200, 201-210, 900-410, 789.) and there was a a test ( AA pp. 450)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm looking for a regex which gives me `2 AA pp. 184-185`, `194-200`, `201-210`, `900-410`, `789.` and `AA pp 450` from:

```
RA pp 24-25; 2 AA pp. 184-185, 194-200, 201-210, 900-410, 789.
```

I've come up with this so far:

```
([\(|;]\s*(\d+)?\s*AA\s*p+\.?\s*((\d+)([\s*|\-+?](\d+))\s*,\s*)*(\d+)\.?[;|\)])
```

using re.findAll but it gives me:

```
[('; 2 AA pp. 184-185, 194-200, 201-210, 900-410, 789.)', '2', '900-410, ', '900', '-410', '410', '789'), ('( AA pp. 450)', '', '', '', '', '', '450')]
```

How do i get what i want. I'm a newbie and have been using pythex.org to practice regex.

**Additional information:**

Thanks SiHa, Here is the criteria. The strings am after start with a ( or a ; followed by number (this is optional btw) and have AA followed by a single or two ps, followed by number ranges or just a number followed by a ; or )

here are some examples:

```
(2 AA p. 127, 128.)

(AA p. 61; 1 RT pp. 24-27.) --> i dont want anything after semicolon

(AA p. 64, lines 9-14.) --> dont want anything after comma

(AA p. 127, 200.)
```

Comment: additionally it would be great if someone could tell me how to get the number ranges mentioned in the above string as regex groups that i can individually manipulate. For example: 184-185 in group, 194-200 in another and so on.

Comment: You need to provide more information. It's easy to write a Regex that would match that single string, but what criteria should the matches actually be based on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?:([-\d\w ]+)[;,.] ?)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"RA pp 24-25; 2 AA pp. 184-185, 194-200, 201-210, 900-410, 789."

print re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Gives:

> [u'RA pp 24-25', u'2 AA pp', u'184-185', u'194-200', u'201-210', u'900-410', u'789']

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re.split`:

```
string = "RA pp 24-25; 2 AA pp. 184-185, 194-200, 201-210, 900-410, 789."
print re.split(r'[;,]\s*', string)
```

The output is:

```
['RA pp 24-25', '2 AA pp. 184-185', '194-200', '201-210', '900-410', '789.']
```